# Create Metric Math alarm using single metric in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am trying to create alarm in cloudwatch. I have a metric where I emit **1.0** for success and **0.0** for failure. The **SUM** statistic is supposed to me give all the successful request while **SAMPLE COUNT** should give all the requests(including failed one). I want to create an alarm where if **SUM(metric)/SAMPLE COUNT(metric) <= threshold** it alarms. I am not able to do the same using a single metric. The SAMPLE COUNT option does not show up. Am I expected to create two metrics in order to achieve this in cloudwatch if it is not possible via single metric?

Answer (score 1):

SUM(metric)/SAMPLE COUNT(metric) is the definition of average. Can you use the Average statistic?